# Excluding entries in an entry query with an array of IDs (PHP)

Tags: php, elementquery

This seems more like a PHP question than a Craft CMS question, but since it's related to an entry query I'm trying to create I figured someone from the Craft community might know. I'm having trouble creating a query that excludes some IDs that are pulled from another entry field. (It's a blog with a "Featured Entries" field at the top, if there are featured entries, they should be excluded from the feed below.)

My code looks like this:

```php
$excluded = implode(',',$entry->featuredMedia->ids());
$entries = Entry::find()->section('blog');
$entries->id(['not', $excluded);
```

Which results in an error `"Invalid numeric value: 1602,1630"` (The IDs of my excluded entries)

Strangely enough, this example works:

```php
$excluded = $entry->featuredMedia->ids();
$entries = Entry::find()->section('blog');
$entries->id(['not', $excluded[0], $excluded[1]]);
```

I know this has something to do with implode() returning a string instead of numeric values, but I can't figure out how to get the right format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `implode` function will turn the array of IDs into a comma-separated string. Then you're putting that into an array with `'not'` as the first element, so the parameter you're passing to `id()` looks like this:

```php
['not', '1602,1630']
```

This isn't one of the [supported formats](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html#id) – if you want to exclude a list of IDs, you pass an array of IDs with `'not'` as the first element:

```php
['not', 1602, 1630]
```

Instead of using `implode`, you can use the array returned by your first query as-is, only adding `'not'` at the beginning using [`array_unshift`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php):

```php
$excluded = $entry->featuredMedia->ids();
array_unshift($excluded, 'not');

$entries = Entry::find()
    ->section('blog')
    ->id($excluded)
    ->all();
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and seems obvious in retrospect. Thanks for the help!